# How to add whitespace between generated numbers - PHP

Tags: php, whitespace

I generated a 16 digit number using the mt_rand function. I'm trying to add a whitespace after every four-digit

For example: 4933 2375 1949 8010 (this is what I'm trying to achieve)

Here is my code

```
function generatenumber($limit, $prefix){
    $code = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) { 
        $code .= mt_rand(0, 9); 
    }
    return $prefix.$code;
}

generatenumber(15, 4);

result: 4933237519498010 // Need a whitespace after every four digit
```

Comment: Check if i%4 is zero and append a space on code. PHP dont have datatypes restrictions so it should be easy

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it! I'm relatively new to programming language. Could you show me how I can achieve this (by answering the question) Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`chunk_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php):

```php
<?php

function generatenumber($limit, $prefix){
    $code = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) { 
        $code .= mt_rand(0, 9); 
    }
    return chunk_split($prefix . $code, 4, ' ');
}

echo generatenumber(15, 4);
```

> 4763 7818 1147 5040

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BCoMwDIbvfYochFos4mA7jCp7FHE1rmWzLV0LA/HZu04Hg@WQ8IfvI3HKpdRenHKETNHIoK2BGxr0Q0AT5yv6snjoWQcOhfM46RdbCOQqpB0ROqBUbHmymdR50QjIs4Vd@4SqYrDARv3MuoM59H4wY9lwODOxA@vWPYboDUgVzb1/uocO5fd6vdkcjhwoUCYIISshKJX9f/twyhQTKb0B)

Comment: nice, didn't know this existed

Comment: The easiest one! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way would be check every nth iteration if the current iteration (+1 since it's 0 indexed) is divisible by `$prefix`.

```
function generatenumber($limit, $prefix) {
    $code = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) { 
        
        if (($i + 1) % $prefix === 0) {
            $code .= ' ';
        }
        
        $code .= mt_rand(0, 9); 
        
    }

    return $prefix.$code;
}

generatenumber(15, 4);
```

Result: `4910 2555 3930 7438`

Answer (score 0):

You can work with modulo to figure out when 4 (prefix here) numbers are generated to put a whitespace:

```
function generatenumber($limit, $prefix){
    $code = '';
    for($i = 1; $i <= $limit; $i++) { 
        $code .= mt_rand(0, 9);
        if($i % $prefix == 0)
            $code .= " "; 
    }
    return $code;
}

echo generatenumber(16, 4);
```